# 4D visualization in Matlab (Surface and Mesh)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mesh, surface, 4d

I have four variables, x,y,z,t. I would like to show (x,y,z) in form of a surface such that the color of the surface is determined by t. I want to assign "t" to color bar. Now, color bar is corresponding to z, I want to have it corresponding to "t" my 4th variable.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Could you post your code? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: X=1:10; Y=1:14; [x y]=meshgrid(X,Y);z=RESULT(:,1); t = RESULT(:,2) surf(x,y,z), colorbar

Comment: Do **NOT** post code as comments. *Edit*  the question by pressing the `edit` button below the tags on your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's very easy: just use

```
surf(x, y, z, t)
```

From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html),

> `surf(X,Y,Z,C)` uses `C` to define color. MATLAB® performs a linear transformation on this data to obtain colors from the current colormap.

Here's an example:

```
x = linspace(0,pi,50);
y = linspace(0,pi/2,50);
z = bsxfun(@times, sin(x), sin(y.')); %'
t = bsxfun(@minus, x, y.'); %'// example data;
surf(x,y,z,t); %// draw surface
colorbar %// show colorbar
```

[image]

Comment: Ghe, using `bsxfun` even though it's uncalled for, splendid.

Comment: @Adriaan The first idea that came to my mind was to use a separable function as an example. And that's what `bsxfun` does :-)